# How does aspect condition an ergative split?

Tags: syntax, aspect, ergativity

I've never heard of a natural language that has ergative-absolutive marking alone.   From what I've read, languages with said marking also have nominative-accusative marking, with the choice or "split" between the two types of marking conditioned by some semantic or syntactic factor.  For example, in some languages we see the following:  Clauses whose subjects are most likely to be agents have nominative-accusative marking.   So we have "I-nom.  ate the pork-acc.."   But clauses whose subjects are less likely to be agents have ergative-absolutive marking.   So we have "The rock-erg. hit the car-abs."

But from what I've read, said split can be conditioned by factors other than the agency, including aspect!   Though I know that aspect *does* condition such a split, but *why* does it do so?   What's the semantic or cognitive logic behind this?

Comment: Can you give any references or example languages for aspect conditioning split-ergativity?

Comment: OK, a bit of looking and I'll (partly) answer myself. Languages of the Indo-Iranian group (within the weird and exotic Indo-European family) show this behaviour, with perfective clauses having ergative marking while imperfective aspect clauses take accusative marking.

Comment: Well, there's Hindi-Urdu:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_ergativity.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut: Indo-what? Is this some obscure family spoken under a rock in the Indus valley or something? But seriously, could you give an example of such a perfective clause with ergative marking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's Jessica Coon's analysis of how split ergativity works in Chol, a Mayan language:

1. The language has ergative/absolutive marking in simple (monoclausal) sentences.
2. Ergative and genitive are marked identically.
3. The subject of nominalizations is marked with ergative/genitive.
4. Progressives are biclausal, and derived from nominalizations.

Thus, in a perfective sentence with one argument, the argument will be marked with the absolutive (by point 1).  In a imperfective/progressive single-argument sentence, the argument will be marked with ergative/genitive (by 3 and 4).  In sentences with two arguments, ergative/absolutive marking is observed for both perfectives and imperfectives.

The above analysis and underlying data are from [an abstract](http://www.kongresuak.ehu.es/p275-shergact/en/contenidos/informacion/ergativity_programme/en_program/adjuntos/Jessica_Coon.pdf) (pdf); the author has several papers on the subject whose bibliographic information can be found in [her CV](http://web.mit.edu/jcoon/www/Jessica_Coon/Home_files/jcooncv.pdf) (pdf).

So, at least in this language, the appearance of split ergativity is the result of a confluence of quite common linguistic traits (2, 3, and 4 above all occur independently of each other very often.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the following chapter is a useful reference:

Hiroyuki Ura. 2007. "A Parametric Syntax Of Aspectually Conditioned Split-Ergativity". In: *Ergativity: Emerging Issues*, eds. Alana Johns, Diane Massam, and Juvenal Ndayiragije.

> In some languages (e.g., Georgian, Hindi, Samoan, Nepali, etc.), where
>   the ergative  system  coexists  with  the  accusative  one,  the 
>   alternation  between  ergativity  and  accusativity is determined by
>   aspectuality (cf. DeLancey 1981, Dixon 1994, and Ura  2000).  In  this
>   paper,  I  will  explore  the  syntactic  mechanism  of  the 
>   aspectually  conditioned  split-ergativity  and  try  to  explicate 
>   the  parameter  settings  which  distinguish the languages with the
>   aspectually conditioned split-ergativity from the  ergative languages
>   with no such split and from the accusative languages in general.